# I can't use str.join() to join strings in list

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I created a list in Jinja2 that is sent to the function in Flask but when I try to use str.join('/', this_list) this function returns a list with words divided by '/'.

Jinja2 snippet:

```
{% set list1 = request.path[1:].split('/') %}
<a href="/activity/delete/{{ user_id }}/{{ activity.activity_id}}/{{ list1 }}">Delete</a>
```

It returns

```
 ['activity', 'details', '98353a241d934856991cc11c5219bc4e', '8a30f573235f4f2c9cac2b516e5bfe42']
```

Using str.join('/', returned_value) I get this:

```
[/'/a/c/t/i/v/i/t/y/'/,/ /'/d/e/t/a/i/l/s/'/,/ /'/9/8/3/5/3/a/2/4/1/d/9/3/4/8/5/6/9/9/1/c/c/1/1/c/5/2/1/9/b/c/4/e/'/,/ /'/8/a/3/0/f/5/7/3/2/3/5/f/4/f/2/c/9/c/a/c/2/b/5/1/6/e/5/b/f/e/4/2/'/]
```

I would like to get:

activity/details/98353a241d934856991cc11c5219bc4e/8a30f573235f4f2c9cac2b516e5bfe42

How to do it?

Comment: `"/".join(['activity', 'details', '98353a241d934856991cc11c5219bc4e', '8a30f573235f4f2c9cac2b516e5bfe42'])`

Comment: @McGrady I still get the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert `string` to `list`

```
import ast
returned_value = ast.literal_eval(returned_value)
"/".join(returned_value) #str.join('/', returned_value) also works.
```

Comment: It works the same for this syntax. "/".join(returned_value) is the same as str.join('/', returned_value) in Python3. Sorry that I'm duplicating the anserws but you both said almost the same.

Comment: Check my answer. Its not about your syntax